# How to deep copy an object in javascript as object not as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-copy

How to deep copy an object in javascript as object not as array

```
var x = {attr1: "value", attr2: "value"};
var y = $.extend(true, [], x);
var z = $.extend(true, [], x);

alert($.type(x)); // object
alert($.type(y)); // array [ why not object too ]
alert($.type(z)); // array [ why not object too ]
```

Comment: RTFM: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). "Target…The object to extend. It will receive the new properties."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
var y = $.extend(true, [], x);
```

Try

```
var y = $.extend(true, {}, x);
                       ^^--------- Empty object instead of empty Array
```

Comment: I've tried several different ways of doing this, but this one works the best for object 'arrays'

Answer (score 0):

To make a deep copy of an object in javascript is to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)). In the context of your question, this could be done as follows:

```
var x = {attr1: "value", attr2: "value"};
var deep_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
```